# Converting R time column to specific strings

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column representing time in a data frame in R.

when I call the str() function on the column it says something like this

```
>str(df2$Time)
 Factor w/ 1441 levels "","00:01","00:02","00:03",..: 1086 1096 1111 and so on
```

The thing is I want to conver this column into string type such that if the time is less than 12:00, it should get modified to the string "moring" , if time is between 12:00 and 6:00 , it is "daylight" and so on.

The first step I thought was to convert this vector to time type of column of data frame, so I used chron  function.

I typed the following command,

```
>df2$Time<-chron(times=df2$Time,format=c('h:m'))
 Error in convert.times(times., fmt) : format h:m may be incorrect
 In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(out$s) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL"
```

so I guessed I should have added second parameter in format so I tried the following :

```
df2$Time<-chron(time=df2$Time,format=c('h:m:s'))
```

But still got the same error

I know this is just the first step, may be my approach too is wrong. Can anyone suggest me how to convert these time data cells to morning, evening , night etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `df2$Time` is of type factor with hour:minute values like `06:00`. Use `df2$Time <- ifelse(as.numeric(sub("(\\d{1,2}):.*", "\\1", df2$Time)) < 6, "night", "day")` to exchange hour values < 6 with `night` and other values with `day`.

Comment: @lukeA that's a nice solution, you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use chron's `"times"` class and `cut`:

```
library(chron)

# data in reproducible form
df2 <- data.frame(Times = c("00:01","12:02","19:03"))

df2$Times <- times(paste0(df2$Times, ":00")) # append a chron "times" class column
breaks <- c(0, 12, 18, 24) / 24 # times are internally fractions of a day
labels <- c("morning", "daylight", "evening")
df2$ind <- cut(df2$Times, breaks, labels, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

which gives:

```
> df2
     Times      ind
1 00:01:00  morning
2 12:02:00 daylight
3 19:03:00  evening
```

Next time please supply your data in reproducible form.

*REVISED*  Minor simplification and fixed typo.

Comment: sorry but I am new here. What exactly does reproducible form mean?

Comment: It means it is self contained and in a form that R can directly read without manual work.  i.e. it should be possible to copy the data and code to the clipboard from your post and then just paste it into an R session to run it.  See and the `dput` command and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Typo. Have fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing with `lubridate` (sorry Joran, i like this package), and functions `hour` and `hm`:

```
Time <- hour(hm("13:24","19:32","3:45","08:25", "21:45", "11:13", "00:00"))
your_breaks <- hour(hm("00:00", "6:00", "12:00", "18:00", "23:59"))
your_labels <- c("Night", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening")
cut(x=Time, breaks=your_breaks, labels=your_labels, include.lowest=TRUE)

[1] Afternoon Evening   Night     Morning   Evening   Morning   Night
```

Answer (score 1):

First some reproducible example:

```
time <- expand.grid(0:23,0:59)
time <- apply(time,1,function(x)sprintf("%02i:%02i",x[1],x[2]))
```

One way to go is to paste in front of your hour data some fake date, so that you can parse your time data as POSIXct and then use `cut` to sort them:

```
time <- strptime(paste("01/01/01",time),"%y/%m/%d %H:%M")

cut(time,
    breaks= as.POSIXct(paste("2001-01-01",
                       c("00:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00", "23:59:59"))),
    labels=c('morning','afternoon','night'))
```

Comment: What will the above command do? I mean how will it partition? I want to part as between 8 pm to 6 am = night , 6 am to 8 am and 5:30 pm to 8:00 pm as twighlight and 8 am to 5:30 pm as daylight. What modifications should I perform in the above command.

Comment: The breaks are conveniently given in the argument `breaks`.  So you will have to modify it the following way: `cut(time, breaks= as.POSIXct(paste("2001-01-01",c("00:00:00", "06:00:00", "08:00:00",17:30:00","20:00:00","23:59:59"))),labels=c('night','twilight','daylight','twilight','night'))`

Comment: I did it, but got a warning :

duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

Comment: That happens if you start your break argument with "00:00:00" and finish it with "00:00:00" as well. That s why i used "23:59:59". You can't repeat a breaking point.